# How to set SubGrid data binding conditional?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I've followed the demo to setup the master/detail grids (or hierarchy grids), they works fine as intended.
However I'd like to make improvement by asking how to make SubGrid data binding conditional.

By default if the MasterGrid returned 10 rows, then the data binding to the SubGrid, which is the url to Controller/Action, were called 10 times, with each one pass in the different ID from MasterGrid.

In my case I only need to call the data bind to SubGrid when a value in MasterGrid has met the requirement.
i.e. for each row of MasterGrid returned, only if the column MyFlag=1, then I need to call the SubGrid.
So out of 10 rows turned, if only 3 rows has MyFlag=1, then the data call to SubGrid only need to be 3 times, instead of 10.

I am not sure how to do that, please advise.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

The `SubGrid` should only be accessed when you expand `MasterGrid` so actually you should **not** have 10 accesses to the server.

If you want to control if a row in `MasterGrid` can be expanded, then you need to implement in the `detailInit` function of the `MasterGrid` the logic for deciding -depending on the content of the `MasterGrid` (`MyFlag` equals `1`)- if the `SubGrid` has to be created or do just nothing.

What this approach does not prevent is having the expansion indicator (little triangle) from being shown.

Comment: Thank you OnaBai!  However I have to say that SubGrid are called multiple times, I checked using F12 in Chrome, it shows 10 calls to SubGrid:

Comment: I've posted teh same question on Telerik's Kendo forum, this answer works.  [http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/grid/how-to-set-subgrid-data-binding-conditional-.aspx#boCDoa6aG2OF1P8AAFTdxQ](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/grid/how-to-set-subgrid-data-binding-conditional-.aspx#boCDoa6aG2OF1P8AAFTdxQ)

Comment: How did you define detailInit before. Here are controlling at server side what to publish (inefficient anyway) but glad it works for you.

Comment: I honestly don't know much about detailInit, I am new to MVC/Kendo, I was just followed the demo/sample code on KendoUI Grid.  However, I did find out that if you have all SubGrid expanded on load (as in my case), then all SubGrid bind will be called, if you have SubGrid all collapsed on load, then SubGrid databind are not called until you click on the little triangle as you've described earlier.  So the "this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row"));" triggers the SubGrid call?

Comment: Ok! that's the missing part :-) But that's because you have all expanded. If you expand -lets say- only second then only that second row is loaded.

Comment: yes, that's right. then good thing of that solution (provided link above) is that the little triangle is not shown for those rows that I don't need subgrid to be bound.  Thank you OnaBai for your help ;-)